# How to center the p element vertically in v-card on Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, web-frontend

The code is shown below.

```html
<v-container fluid>
    <!-- page title -->
    <v-row>
      …
    </v-row>
    <!-- body -->
    <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
      <!-- input -->
      <v-col cols="5">
        <v-card outlined height="80vh" max-height="80vh" class="pa-8">
          <!-- image upload -->
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-file-input
                accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                chips
                label="Choose an image(JPG or PNG)"
                outlined
                prepend-icon="image"
                show-size
                v-model="image"
                @change="previewImage"
                @click:clear="clearAll"
              ></v-file-input>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <!-- image preview -->
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <p v-if="no_image" class="text-center text-h4 grey--text">
                Image Preview
              </p>
              <v-img v-else :src="imageUrl" contain max-height="55vh"></v-img>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
      <!-- button -->
      <v-col align-self="center" cols="2">
        …
      </v-col>
      <!-- output -->
      <v-col cols="5" align-self="center">
        …
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Current style is [image: Current Style]

but the p element "Image Preview" is expected to be centered vertically in the v-card.
I have tried to add some properties like `align="center"`, `class="align-center"`, `align-self="center"` and more to some relative elements but none of them work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is enough to center the second div in the middle of the height.

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
    </v-row>
    <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="5">
        <v-card outlined height="80vh" max-height="80vh" class="pa-8 d-flex flex-column">
          <v-row class="flex-grow-0">
            <v-col>
              <v-file-input accept="image/png, image/jpeg" chips label="Choose an image(JPG or PNG)" outlined
                prepend-icon="image">
              </v-file-input>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col class="d-flex flex-column justify-center">
              <p class="text-center text-h4 grey--text">
                Image Preview
              </p>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col align-self="center" cols="2">
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="5" align-self="center">
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

This is how it looks

[image]

The additional margin under the text comes from that one

[image]

---

Here is a really nice + short cheatsheet regarding flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Oh yeah you got me! Thanks a lot! Actually I wanted the p element to be centered in the whole v-card rather than the part of it except for file upload, but now I think the latter is more reasonable. By the way, could you tell me what tool in the image in your answer is? It looks like CodePen but is not.

Comment: @PolarisXu this is just some local code + the browser `flex` highlight that you have when you click an element that is using flexbox.

Answer (score -2):

Use display flex property:

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Hi, please put more effort into your answer.